# Core Data - How to access entity attribute?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I have 2 entities. Athlete and Eval. Athlete has a to-many relationship with Eval. An Athlete can have multiple Evals but an Eval can have only 1 Athlete. The first view controller that displays a table view controller for Athlete. It display all the Athletes. When you click on an Athlete is takes you to a table view controller which displays all Evals for that Athlete. How can I display the attributes from the eval at the top of the evalArray[0] in my Athlete table view?

This is what I have so far:

allEvals.h

```
Eval *mostRecentEval = evalArray.firstObject;
AllAthletes *allAthletes = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"allAthletes"];
allAthletes.evalLastUpdated = mostRecentEval.date_recorded;

NSLog(@"%@",mostRecentEval.date_recorded);
```

When I log it, it correctly displays the attribute, but when I go to all athletes, where I log it again when the view appears, it says (null). Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: what happens when you select an eval?

Comment: @Carl Veazey It's just a detail view of the eval in which you can edit its attributes and save it.

Comment: And you want this to be visible from the Athlete view, that is, prior to the list of all the evals?

Comment: Yes, I want to display an eval attribute on each cell in the athlete table view.

Comment: You said the athlete has many evals though - which one do you want to show?

Comment: The most recent. The one that is at array[0]?

Comment: Sort the evals for that athlete by date, then choose the most recent one?

Comment: @CarlVeazey I did that above as you can see in my updated question, but it returns null :(

Comment: When are you doing that?

Comment: @CarlVeazey if you're talking about the nslog on allathletes, I check on viewDidAppear. if you're talking about all the code above, im doing it on viewdidappear on allevals.

Comment: In the evals view, aren't you coming from the athletes view? Don't you want to show this in the athletes table cell? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, thats absolutely correct.

Comment: @CarlVeazey But I can't set the text in the cell because it returns (null). Even though in the other controller it had the correct value.

Comment: Well, you created a new instance from your evals view and set it there - so it's not going to be set in your athletes view. Did you try implementing the table view data source method as described in my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Athletes view controller, inside `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, for the `Athlete` for that row, get their `Eval` objects and sort them by date (however you are building the eval array) and then get the most recent one and use it to populate the label on your athlete table view cell.

Comment: It didn't work, but I know it would work. The problem that I had was I incorrectly set up the eval. When I clicked on an athlete, it showed me all evals. The evals didn't have an owner, it was everyones evals not just the athlete tapped. Working on that now, and appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Well how are you ordering the Evals in the table view with all of the Evals? Just keep the ordering in an `NSArray` and then in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, get the row index out of the index path and then get the element at that index in your `NSArray`. Et voilà, you have the Eval that the user tapped on!

Comment: No, I want to access the evals from the athlete view. So how can I tranverse two entities? on the first view where it shows the athletes, I have the athlete's name as the main text on the view cell. I want the subtitle text to be an attribute of Eval that correlates to each athlete. so I will have many many many eval attributes. not just the one that was selected.

Answer (score 0):

in coreData you dont use an index to refer to your "relationships"

you will know what "Athlete" was selected on your table data source,

so after tapping on the cell, get the "Eval" for that "Athlete"

if you are using an array with the Athletes:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 Athlete *selectedAthlete = [self.AthletesArray objectForIndex: indexPath.row];
 //deal with push new view controller, send the selectedAthlete
}
```

then when you want to get your Eval for that athlete

do a predicate with your property = selectedAthlete

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(athleteRelation =%@)", selectedAthlete];
```

now is the eval for the selected athlete

good luck

Comment: I know how to know which was selected, I'm trying to find the correlating index path for the Eval. So for Athlete1 I want Eval1, Athlete2 I want Eval2. I want to put eval attributes in the Athlete table view.

Comment: hi, there is no index in CD, for the relationship, create a relationship [one to many] between your Athlete and Eval